# Linux "at" command works fine when running from shell but fails when run from webserver

Tags: php, linux, apache, bash, shell

I'm using "at" in order to set future actions set by users on RHEL6.4.
The command I'm using from php is

```
exec("echo \"php $script_path\" | at $run_time");
```

where the script path has been set as has the run time. This works 100% fine when I run from a shell initiated with php -a. When it runs from the webserver the job is created, but it doesn't seem to run.

1. I have verified :  The apache user has full read-write-execute
       access to the directory and all folders therein.
2. The exec command
       is running (the at job is created, after all.)
3. I have verified the
       job is looking for the right path on the server.

I'm not sure what else I can do to get this at command to run the script properly. Any suggestions?

Thank you for your help.

---

Update: 
I went ahead and created a page that linked to the script I'm trying to auto-run and launched it in that way. The script itself works fine when run as apache that way, meaning it's definitely something that "at" is doing. I ran print_r($_ENV) to determine the environment variables being used. The only thing that shows up is a number 1.

---

Update 2: 
I ran an at -c on each job, the one that never seems to run, and the one that works just fine. There seems to be much more content on the one that does work VS the one that doesn't. 65 worked (ran from shell)

```
at -c 65
#!/bin/sh
# atrun uid=0 gid=0
# mail root 0
umask 22
HOSTNAME=ipdb-sys.ipdb.lab; export HOSTNAME
SHELL=/bin/bash; export SHELL
HISTSIZE=1000; export HISTSIZE
SSH_CLIENT=143.166.167.124\ 53008\ 22; export SSH_CLIENT
QTDIR=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3; export QTDIR
QTINC=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/include; export QTINC
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0; export SSH_TTY
USER=root; export USER
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01\;34:ln=01\;36:mh=00:pi=40\;33:so=01\;35:do=01\;35:bd=40\;33\;01:cd=40\;33\;01:or=40\;31\;01:mi=01\;05\;37\;41:su=37\;41:sg=30\;43:ca=30\;41:tw=30\;42:ow=34\;42:st=37\;44:ex=01\;32:\*.tar=01\;31:\*.tgz=01\;31:\*.arj=01\;31:\*.taz=01\;31:\*.lzh=01\;31:\*.lzma=01\;31:\*.tlz=01\;31:\*.txz=01\;31:\*.zip=01\;31:\*.z=01\;31:\*.Z=01\;31:\*.dz=01\;31:\*.gz=01\;31:\*.lz=01\;31:\*.xz=01\;31:\*.bz2=01\;31:\*.tbz=01\;31:\*.tbz2=01\;31:\*.bz=01\;31:\*.tz=01\;31:\*.deb=01\;31:\*.rpm=01\;31:\*.jar=01\;31:\*.rar=01\;31:\*.ace=01\;31:\*.zoo=01\;31:\*.cpio=01\;31:\*.7z=01\;31:\*.rz=01\;31:\*.jpg=01\;35:\*.jpeg=01\;35:\*.gif=01\;35:\*.bmp=01\;35:\*.pbm=01\;35:\*.pgm=01\;35:\*.ppm=01\;35:\*.tga=01\;35:\*.xbm=01\;35:\*.xpm=01\;35:\*.tif=01\;35:\*.tiff=01\;35:\*.png=01\;35:\*.svg=01\;35:\*.svgz=01\;35:\*.mng=01\;35:\*.pcx=01\;35:\*.mov=01\;35:\*.mpg=01\;35:\*.mpeg=01\;35:\*.m2v=01\;35:\*.mkv=01\;35:\*.ogm=01\;35:\*.mp4=01\;35:\*.m4v=01\;35:\*.mp4v=01\;35:\*.vob=01\;35:\*.qt=01\;35:\*.nuv=01\;35:\*.wmv=01\;35:\*.asf=01\;35:\*.rm=01\;35:\*.rmvb=01\;35:\*.flc=01\;35:\*.avi=01\;35:\*.fli=01\;35:\*.flv=01\;35:\*.gl=01\;35:\*.dl=01\;35:\*.xcf=01\;35:\*.xwd=01\;35:\*.yuv=01\;35:\*.cgm=01\;35:\*.emf=01\;35:\*.axv=01\;35:\*.anx=01\;35:\*.ogv=01\;35:\*.ogx=01\;35:\*.aac=01\;36:\*.au=01\;36:\*.flac=01\;36:\*.mid=01\;36:\*.midi=01\;36:\*.mka=01\;36:\*.mp3=01\;36:\*.mpc=01\;36:\*.ogg=01\;36:\*.ra=01\;36:\*.wav=01\;36:\*.axa=01\;36:\*.oga=01\;36:\*.spx=01\;36:\*.xspf=01\;36:; export LS_COLORS
WEBROOT=/var/www; export WEBROOT
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/root; export MAIL
PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/dell/srvadmin/bin:/opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin:/root/bin; export PATH
PWD=/root; export PWD
LANG=en_US.UTF-8; export LANG
MODULEPATH=/usr/share/Modules/modulefiles:/etc/modulefiles; export MODULEPATH
LOADEDMODULES=; export LOADEDMODULES
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups; export HISTCONTROL
SHLVL=1; export SHLVL
HOME=/root; export HOME
LOGNAME=root; export LOGNAME
QTLIB=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/lib; export QTLIB
CVS_RSH=ssh; export CVS_RSH
SSH_CONNECTION=143.166.167.124\ 53008\ 10.180.57.93\ 22; export SSH_CONNECTION
MODULESHOME=/usr/share/Modules; export MODULESHOME
LESSOPEN=\|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh\ %s; export LESSOPEN
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1; export G_BROKEN_FILENAMES
module=\(\)\ {\ \ eval\ \`/usr/bin/modulecmd\ bash\ \$\*\`"
"}; export module
cd /root || {
         echo 'Execution directory inaccessible' >&2
         exit 1
}
${SHELL:-/bin/sh} << 'marcinDELIMITER145f56ce'
php /var/www/ipdb5.0/unattend/release.php

marcinDELIMITER145f56ce
```

Job 68 didn't.

```
at -c 68
#!/bin/sh
# atrun uid=48 gid=48
# mail apache 1
umask 22
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin; export PATH
RUNLEVEL=3; export RUNLEVEL
runlevel=3; export runlevel
PWD=/var/www/ipdb5.0/run; export PWD
LANGSH_SOURCED=1; export LANGSH_SOURCED
LANG=C; export LANG
PREVLEVEL=N; export PREVLEVEL
previous=N; export previous
CONSOLETYPE=vt; export CONSOLETYPE
SHLVL=4; export SHLVL
UPSTART_INSTANCE=; export UPSTART_INSTANCE
UPSTART_EVENTS=runlevel; export UPSTART_EVENTS
UPSTART_JOB=rc; export UPSTART_JOB
cd /var/www/ipdb5\.0/run || {
         echo 'Execution directory inaccessible' >&2
         exit 1
}
${SHELL:-/bin/sh} << 'marcinDELIMITER348f4254'
php /usr/bin/php /var/www/ipdb5.0/unattend/release.php

marcinDELIMITER348f4254
```

Don't know if you guys can devine any more out of this than I can, but I figured it wouldn't hurt to post to see.

Comment: It could be that the user that the `at` job is running as does not have php in its path.  Try `exec("echo \"/full/path/to/php $script_path\" | at $run_time");` to see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Hi mti2935, you had my hopes sky-high. Unfortunately that wasn't the issue. I did as suggested and added /usr/bin/php before my script path. It didn't seem to make a difference. 

Are you aware of a way to output errors from at jobs? I haven't been able to find anything, though finding information on a command named something as common as the word "at" is a pain...

Comment: @Ethan, there's the -m option to at.

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the only way. When I enable -m I don't receive any message in my mail indicating there's an issue with the script execution.

Comment: You need to find what differences there are between your environment and the web server's environment.

Comment: I don't disagree... And yet what else is there truly besides what we've already verified here? Access, check. Paths, check. At command syntax, check.

Comment: You're saying that when you run it through the web server, the `at` job is created, but it doesn't seem to run. So, I'm wondering if somehow that command is getting botched when you run it through the web server. After you run it through the web server, and the at job is created, try doing `at -l` to list all of the `at` jobs.  Then, find the one that was created, and do `at -c xxx` (where xxx is the id of the at job that we are interested in). This should produce a bunch of output including environment stuff, etc., but at the end should be the command that to be executed.  Does it look right?

Comment: Yep, looks good. The command to run is "PHP /var/www/ipdb5.0/unattend/release.php" exactly as expected.

Comment: Don't know the answer, but check https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2011-June/400025.html as I think the fact that Apache isn't run from shell might be the issue. NOTE this warning: https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2011-June/400026.html

Comment: I'd run 'env' in both environments to see what variables are exported.  And you can always try redirecting stdout and stderr to something and see what turns up.

Comment: Hi @Craniumonempty, thank you for the suggestion. I don't believe that the script should require a shell, since I'm not letting users do anything interactive, but it's worth a try to see if that's the issue. 

-some guy I'll give that a shot and see what I see.

Comment: @craniumonempty I made the changes suggested in the fedoraproject article, with no success. Thanks for the article, any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the answer. It turns out you need three things to be true that I hadn't set before.

1. You need to have the absolute path to the program you're calling
   (php had to be /usr/bin/php) - Thanks mti2935.
2. You need to have a shell set up for your apache user. - Thanks
   for getting me started in this direction craniumonempty. The command
   I had to run was : `sudo chsh -s /bin/bash username`
3. Lastly you have to have an at.allow file created with the
   www-data group and apache user in it. (Make sure there is NOT a
   at.deny file, as this will counteract the allow.).

Once all of these are set the at will run successfully from your webserver. Also, be sure to have the basics which I went over in the main post. Give read/write/execute to apache for the script you're running, make sure the script itself works without running it with at, and verify the at job is being created.

Thank you all for the assistance.

Comment: apache with shell isn't a wise option.
Take a look at https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2011-June/400095.html